# In Excel, how can I set up a VBA ComboBox so that it still works if the worksheet is copied?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I can create an ActiveX ComboBox in a worksheet and configure it to give me a list of all worksheets, and it will activate whichever worksheet I select.

However, if I copy the worksheet containing the ComboBox, the new ComboBox is dead.  I have to duplicate all the VBA code that makes it work, changing the labels accordingly.

Is there any way to set it up so that it works automatically if I copy the worksheet?

This is how I'm currently doing it:

**Microsoft Excel Objects \ ThisWorkbook:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' Rebuild the list of sheets for the worksheet ComboBox.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
        Next

End Sub
```

**Microsoft Excel Objects \ Sheet1(Sheet1):**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        Sheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: since each ComboBox has a separate event, you will always need to assign the event code for each sheet you copy with the ComboBox in it. One thing you could do is write a separate Sub to Activate the Sheet and just pass the ComboBox ListItem to that sub for each ComboBox ... actually, not sure that is really even worth it!

Comment: Using VBE Extensibility it would be possible but definitely overkill. What I would do is change the event procedure instead of `Sheet1` make it say `Me`, and I *think* then the code should be portable between sheets. If the copied sheets do not preserve the ComboBox name, then just rename the ComboBox instead of revising each CB's event procedure.

Comment: I was just playing around with what @DavidZemens suggested as he was writing his comment. I will tell you what I did that worked. 1) Created a ComboBox 2) named it something specific (`cbSheet` in my case). 3) tested your code, but replaced `Sheet1` with Me and 4) Copy the sheet I had the combobox on and it tested the code again, which worked perfectly without having to make any adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your Workbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call PopulateBoxes(Sheet1)
End Sub
```

In a standard module, do this:

```
Sub PopulateBoxes(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    'Populate the combobox on sheet 1
    Dim obj
    Set obj = ws.OLEObjects.Item("ComboBox1").Object
    obj.Clear
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        obj.AddItem sht.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Then, in your Sheet1 module, make this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    With Me.ComboBox1
        Sheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub WOrksheet_Activate()
    Call PopulateBoxes(Me)
End Sub
```

Now, the code for each ComboBox should be functional even after copying sheets.

Comment: Hi, @DavidZemens.  Thank you for that.  I tried your suggested code.  There's a problem in that after I use the ComboBox to switch to another sheet, if I change back (manually) to the source sheet, I get an error:  Run-time error 381:  Could not get the List property.  Invalid property array index.  This error references the line "Sheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Activate".

Comment: I discovered that when coming back to the original sheet, the combo box got "bounced", but it triggered with a list index choice of zero.  I fixed it by rewriting the ComboBox1_Change function to grab the index number (+1) , and only run the line that activates the sheet if the index number was != 0.  Thanks for providing the base code!